# I am trying to connect to the Xero API to recipe invoices but getting the following error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xero-api

When i am trying to get the invoices using the Xero API i get an error with .get_invoices('').invoices.

Please see the error below:

```
*** XeroRuby::ApiError Exception: Error message: the server returns an error

HTTP status code: 403

Response headers: {"content-length"=>"0", "server"=>"nginx", "xero-correlation-id"=>"c605f5e5-81e7-4763-ae07-093e7cb6f949", "x-appminlimit-remaining"=>"9998", "expires"=>"Thu, 02 Feb 2023 16:45:04 GMT", "cache-control"=>"max-age=0, no-cache, no-store", "pragma"=>"no-cache", "date"=>"Thu, 02 Feb 2023 16:45:04 GMT", "connection"=>"keep-alive", "x-client-tls-ver"=>"tls1.3"}

Response body:
```

Index Controller

```
require 'xero-ruby'

    creds = {
      client_id: '...',
      client_secret: '...',
      grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    }

    xero_client = XeroRuby::ApiClient.new(credentials: creds)

    @token_set = xero_client.get_client_credentials_token

    byebug

    @invoices = xero_client.accounting_api.get_invoices('').invoices
```

Comment: Why the empty string argument?

Comment: Following on from what @tadman and @sallyhornet say it looks like you need to supply at least a `xero-tenant-id` argument to the `get_invoices` method. See examples in the [docs](https://xeroapi.github.io/xero-ruby/accounting/index.html#api-Accounting-getInvoices).

Answer (score 0):

Please can you check the tenant id in your call. Looking at the Xero logs for the correlation id you mention, the tenant id is being sent as "page=1-100"